# Maze function not working with respect to detecting deleted walls

Tags: c++

Have searched on here and have not come across this question yet... looks like a particular method is not working properly.

I have generated a maze using the Aldous-Broder approach. Generating the maze seems to work perfectly, but solving it seems to give me some issues. The reason is because it doesn't seem like setting the walls to false actually works.

When I go back to detect whether the walls are there, so that I can determine whether a particular path can go in that direction, it seems to always output that the wall IS there, even though I can see it is isn't. This is quite a lot of code, but I would appreciate if someone could look through it and tell me where I'm going wrong.

I'm new to C++ so this is early days for me as well -- if you'd like to see more of the code, I'd be more than happy to provide it.

Thanks.

This creates the maze:

```
int main() {

// Initialize.
Randomize();
InitGraphics();
Maze maze(MAZE_ROWS, MAZE_COLS, true); // These are the parameters given in the interface file.
maze.draw();
cout << "Welcome to the Maze!!" << endl;

// Setup.
pointT current_point = setupCurrentPoint(maze);

while (true) {

    // Break out of this when all the cells have been included in the set.
    if (included_point.size() == ALL_CELLS) {
        break;
    }

    // Generate the maze.
    pointT selected_neighbor = generateMaze(current_point, maze);

    // Set the neighbor equal to the current point.
    current_point = selected_neighbor;

}
```

This is the generateMaze function:

```
// Generate the maze.
pointT generateMaze(pointT current_point, Maze maze) {

// Generate a random neighbor.
int picked_neighbor = RandomInteger(0, 3);

// Declare the point.
pointT selected_neighbor = pickANeighbor(current_point, picked_neighbor);

// If it's not within the boundaries of the maze, pick a new neighbor.
while (maze.pointInBounds(selected_neighbor) == false) {  

    // Generate a random neighbor.
    int picked_neighbor = RandomInteger(0, 3);

    selected_neighbor = pickANeighbor(current_point, picked_neighbor);

    if (maze.pointInBounds(selected_neighbor) == true) {
        break;
    }
}

// If the neighbor is excluded, remove the wall and mark it as included.
if (included_point.contains(selected_neighbor) == false) {

    if (maze.isWall(selected_neighbor, current_point) == true) {
        maze.setWall(selected_neighbor, current_point, false);

    }

    // Add the point if it's not already in the set.
    included_point.add(selected_neighbor);      

}

return selected_neighbor;
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to solve the maze:

```
// SOLVE -- THIS PART IS IN PROGRESS. THE ABOVE CODE IS COMPLETELY FINISHED.

// Create a path with just a start location, enqueue it and then dequeue it.
Stack<pointT> start_path = setupPath();
store_paths.enqueue(start_path);
Stack<pointT> shortest_path = store_paths.dequeue();


// If the path ends at the goal, you're finished.
pointT end_point;
end_point.row = MAZE_ROWS - 1;
end_point.col = MAZE_COLS - 1;

pointT popped_point;
popped_point = shortest_path.peek();

while (true) {

    cout << "START AGAIN" << endl;

    // Otherwise, for each neighbor accessible from the last point, make a copy of the path.
        int picked_neighbor = RandomInteger(0, NUM_NEIGHBORS);
        pointT add_point = pickANeighbor(popped_point, picked_neighbor);
        cout << "the point to add is " << toString(add_point) << endl;

        if (maze.pointInBounds(add_point) && !checkForCircle(shortest_path, add_point) &&       !maze.isWall(popped_point, add_point)){
            cout << "the point that is OK is: " << toString(add_point) << endl;
            Stack<pointT> path_copy = shortest_path;
            path_copy.push(add_point);
            store_paths.enqueue(path_copy);

        }


    if (store_paths.size() != 0) {
            // Dequeue the shortest path.
            shortest_path = store_paths.dequeue();

            // Figure out what the last point in it was.
            popped_point = shortest_path.peek();

            // Figure out whether the popped point matches the end point.
            if (popped_point == end_point) {
                cout << "You're done..." << endl;
                //break;
        }
    }
}

// Now trace out the right path.
drawPath(shortest_path, maze);
```

EDIT: In case you also wanted to see the function prototypes:

using namespace std;

```
/* Function prototypes */
Stack<pointT> setupPath();
pointT setupCurrentPoint(Maze maze);
pointT pickANeighbor(pointT point, int picked_neighbor);
pointT generateMaze(pointT current_point, Maze maze);
string toString(pointT point);
bool checkForCircle(Stack<pointT>, pointT);
void drawPath(Stack<pointT> shortest_path, Maze maze);
bool wallBetweenPoints(pointT popped_point, pointT add_point, Maze maze);

/* Private instance variables */
Set<pointT> included_point;
Vector<pointT> select_a_neighbor;
Queue<Stack<pointT> > store_paths;

/* Constants */
const int MAZE_ROWS = 5;
const int MAZE_COLS = 8;
const int ALL_CELLS = (MAZE_ROWS)  * (MAZE_COLS);
const int NUM_NEIGHBORS = 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your entire code so I could not test it fully. But, most probably: in

```
// Generate the maze.
pointT generateMaze(pointT current_point, Maze maze) { ...
```

you are forwarding a *copy* of your maze. Reading it is harmless, but writing it in this function leads to nothing, as the copy gets discarded when you leave the function.

Use a *reference* to `maze` instead; this will make it modify your current maze, rather than a copy:

```
// Generate the maze.
pointT generateMaze(pointT current_point, Maze &maze) { ...
```

Comment: Yes, this ended up being the problem. Thanks very much for your help -- appreciate it.